# Send text from C# .NET application to running Visual Studio Code instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to send text to a Visual Studio Code instance via the command line interface of VSCode in order to display the text in a new unsaved tab?

At the moment i managed to accomplish my task via writing the text to a file and then sending the file.

My solution at the moment is like this example:

```
var result = "This text wants to be displayed in a new visual studio code tab.";
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Temp\\test.txt", result);

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe", "C:\\Temp\\test.txt");
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I also tried passing the string itself to the CLI.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe", result);
```

The result is that a new Tab for every word in the string is created in the Visual Studio Code instance. 
This tells me it may be possible to pass something to the CLI other than a file.

Does anybody know if and how it is doable?

Comment: Anything wrong with a temp file?

Comment: Have you tried using `'` around the text so it's actually the following `var result = "'This text wants to be displayed in a new visual studio code tab.'";` this may allow the VSCode to interpret it as a single string.

Comment: Nothing critical. My ideal solution would simply prefer not to handle file access within my text creation tool.

Comment: @Mauro Thank you for your answer. I tested your suggestion. Unfortunately it gives the same result with multiple tabs. The first Tab has the ' in its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible currently (as per their command line documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-files-and-folders). When you pass the string it is interpreting it as mutiple files and opening a tab for each file (which are created if they dont exist).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is unfortunate but I'm going to try to make a feature request out of this requirement.